# log soap request and response from Wcf web service to a text file using log4net

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, logging

Is there there any simple way of getting a WCF Service to log SOAP requests and responses to a text file.

I want to log the messages on server, just to clarify.

Comment: You can use MS Fiddler to inspect packets on the client or server, and see the full request/response XML. Sometimes it's easier than implementing your own solution.

Comment: I need to write the soap messages to text file, is a requirement, sorry but Fiddler won't solve the problem

Comment: Refer to the following link for setting up log4net with WCF. In each webmethod you can add request and response information to the log file.
http://paulthecyclist.com/tag/log4net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can change the service code to add a behavior, you can hook up an [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) and use whichever logging framework to log at the messages there. You can also look at the [WCF Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) feature, which uses the System.Diagnostic framework to perform the logging (I haven't used log4net yet, maybe they have some trace listener which can be used for this as well).